# Spring MVC: static ResourceBundle

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, internationalization

I have a lot of Controllers that are extends one base Controller which has a static contructor with ResourceBundle generation:

```
static {
   resources = ResourceBundle.getBundle("com.resource.Resources");
}
```

I need it because app's logic based on locale, not only views.

In addition I have a `CookieLocaleResolver` that resolves the current locale from the cookie.

The problem is that base controller's static constructor code executes before the CookieLocaleResolver's resolveLocale method so I am always receive a system's default locale at ResourceBundle and not the current one.

How can I solve it? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because the `static` block is executed at the class initialization time. You need to load the `ResourceBundle` when the controller is called. I would suggest you here to define your controller as a `prototype` and use [`InitializingBean`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/InitializingBean.html) to load the ResourceBundle.

```
public class MyController implements InitializingBean {
    private ResourceBundle resources;

    public void afterPropertiesSet() {
         resources = ResourceBundle.getBundle("com.resource.Resources");
    }
}
```

A better way would be to use the [`ResourceBundleMessageSource`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/context/support/ResourceBundleMessageSource.html) and not use the ResourceBundle directly. If you can, that would be much easier since you don't have to manage the ResourceBundle directly.

I hope that will help you.

[Edit]

The Spring MessageSource provides methods to resolve messages with parameters. If you define a `MessageSource` in your application, you will be also able to access the same messages in the view (JSP page for instance). At last, from the design, that is better if the controller doesn't have a direct reference on the resource bundle, this way your labels/messages are managed in a single place (in your Spring config when you declare the MessageSource).

Comment: thanks for your reply, it is very useful. Can you explain why it is better to use the `ResourceBundleMessageSource`? As I understand its cache more fast that ResourceBundle's but I can't find any examples show that it is more useful...

Comment: And if I add `InitializingBean` inheritance the app is fails with `Name spring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain is not bound in this Context. Returning null` error...

Comment: I described my problem in a new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17443854/spring-mvc-static-resourcebundle-vs-messagesource